# The probability of getting 3 cards from the same kind from a piece of cards

Tags: probability

Given 52 cards of $(1,2,3,..13)$ of $13$ cards from each shape, (4 shapes) what is the probability of
"get 3 cards of the same number and the other 2 cards are different from each other"

I was thinking of calculate it in the following way: $$ \frac{1}{13} \cdot \frac{1}{13} \cdot \frac{1}{13} \cdot \frac{1}{49} \cdot \frac{1}{48}$$

But this is not the current answer and I dont understand what is wrong in my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{52}{5}$ ways to choose the $5$ cards.  Three are $13$ ways to choose the rank of the three cards with the same rank and $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ cards of that rank.

Now for the two different cards, I take the question to mean that hey are also of different rank from the first three cards, so we have $\binom{12}{2}$ ways to choose the ranks of these cards, and $4$ ways to choose a card of each rank.

Finally, the probability is $$\frac{13\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{2}4^2}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Comment: That the last two cards have to be of different rank than the first three makes complete sense. The only question I have in my mind is how one should interpret the last two cards being different from each other. In your working, you choose two ranks for them but you allow the shapes to be the same. By that logic, why would same rank different shapes not count as different? May be the question should have more clearly stated it.

Comment: @MathLover I didn't even think of that.  If you want them to have different shapes as well as different ranks, then there are only $3$ ways to chose the last card.  It's not entirely clearly what "different from each other" means, in the context of the problem.

Comment: Yes may be OP can confirm the interpretation based on what the book considers correct answer.